# Mongoose with NodeJS: Default value for document's Date only updates on server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoose Schema declared like so:

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    timestamp: {type: Number, default: Date.now()},
});
```

I defined a route to create posts which works great. The code I use to create a post is as follows:

```
/* POST Create new post (auth required)*/
router.post('/', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var post = new Post();
  post.save(function(err, post){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

However I have noticed that my posts' timestamps don't change with... with time! In fact they dont't change at all. As an example, here are the last three posts:

```
{
_id: "570aa4c946b52c7656cd8cf5",
__v: 0,
timestamp: 1460313633406
},
{
_id: "570aa4e546b52c7656cd8cf6",
__v: 0,
timestamp: 1460313633406
},
{
_id: "570aa59c46b52c7656cd8cf7",
__v: 0,
timestamp: 1460313633406
}
```

They were all posted within a 20 minute interval, yet they all have the same timestamp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass functions to a mongoose Model, you're assigning a value at the creation of the model.
Use just Date.now instead, it will be called every time you save a entry.

```
default: Date.now() //returns a value at model creation
default: Date.now   //adds the function to the model, mongoose will run any functions passed when a new entry is created -> that is what you need`\
```

Comment: Works great, I hadn't quite gotten the subtle difference between passing a function and passing a function's result. In hindsight it is rather obvious!

Comment: Many people have problems understanding these rather "simple" concepts. It can get even more confusing when there is syntax like `somefunction(param)(anotherparam)` so I like awnsering questions like this because it helps underdtanding basic concepts that not everyone is aware of.

Answer (score 2):

The default value was saved as the date that was instantiated at the time the schema object was created, which happens only when the app is started.

You can use a `pre` hook for the document. The [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre) shows an example similar to the situation you have described.

```
PostSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.timestamp = Date.now();
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Date.now() instantiates a date with a value of **that** moment. It doesn't update if the time changes. Since you want a different value for each document's date, you can't use a default value. Instead, upon creation of each document, set its date to Date.now().